# Retornar lista de datos desde la Vista al Controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo un ActionResult que envía a la Vista una lista de datos.

```
public ActionResult CtasCtes(parametros)
{ //Código desarrollado
  return View(List<>);
}
```

Esos datos que son mostrados, necesito traerlos a otro ActionResult para generar un archivo formato Excel

```
public ActionResult Excel(List<> ActionResult Anterior){}
```

Como los puedo recuperar mediante un @HtmlActionLink?
Existe alguna manera o no es viable?

Comment: Hola, en caso de que sean los mismos datos y no tenga ningún filtro podrías realizarlo desde el controlador, ahora bien, si por fuerza mayor ocupas pasarlo desde la vista ya que va a tener algún cambio, te recomiendo que lo envíes por medio de un modelo a la vista y controles ese listado de esa forma.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, los datos que quiero recuperar son los mismos que se enviaron a la Vista. Como podría realizarlo desde el controlador como indicas?

Comment: Puede sacar el código desarrollado con el que obtienes la lista a un método aparte digamos que tenga de nombre "getList" , así cuando ejecutes @HtmlActionLink a algún endpoint, puedas llamar ese método y retornar la misma información. Espero haya podido resolver tu duda.